# In R: How to change the value of an observation conditionally?

Tags: r

If there is a value in the event date column for the first observation of a company (first row of companyID), I would like R to change the status to 0. Below you can see an example where there is a date in the first observation of companyID 1, so I would like the status to change to 0. However, for companyID 2, there is no date for its first observation so this first observation should remain a 1, and so on.

What I have:

```
companyID   status   event date
   1          2      2012-10-13
   1          2          NA
   1          1      2014-01-06
   1          1          NA
   1          1          NA
   2          1          NA
   2          2      2005-05-22
   2          2          NA
   3          2      2008-03-11
   3          2          NA
   3          2          NA
```

What I want:

```
companyID   status   event date
   1          0      2012-10-13
   1          2          NA
   1          1      2014-01-06
   1          1          NA
   1          1          NA
   2          1          NA
   2          2      2005-05-22
   2          2          NA
   3          0      2008-03-11
   3          2          NA
   3          2          NA
```

Let me know if it is unclear! Thank you in advance for any help :)

Comment: Are a date or NA the only possible values for `event date` ?

Comment: @neilfws yes exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here goes:

```r
df <- read.table(text=
"companyID   status   event_date
   1          2      2012-10-13
   1          2          NA
   1          1      2014-01-06
   1          1          NA
   1          1          NA
   2          1          NA
   2          2      2005-05-22
   2          2          NA
   3          2      2008-03-11
   3          2          NA
   3          2          NA
", header=TRUE ) %>% rename( `event date` = event_date )

df %>% group_by( companyID ) %>%
    mutate( status = replace( status, row_number() == 1 & !is.na(`event date`), 0 ) )
```

Simply using `replace` from base but relying on `row_number` to make sure we get at the first value only.

Output:

```r
# A tibble: 11 x 3
# Groups:   companyID [3]
   companyID status `event date`
       <int>  <dbl> <chr>       
 1         1      0 2012-10-13  
 2         1      2 NA          
 3         1      1 2014-01-06  
 4         1      1 NA          
 5         1      1 NA          
 6         2      1 NA          
 7         2      2 2005-05-22  
 8         2      2 NA          
 9         3      0 2008-03-11  
10         3      2 NA          
11         3      2 NA
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who prefer base

```
firsts <- match(unique(df$companyID),df$companyID)
df$status[firsts][!is.na(df$event_date[firsts])] <- 0
```